# Having trouble finding right way to use loop without creating infinite loop to create a menu... full explanation in body

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, netbeans, while-loop

So I am creating a fake menu for a vet clinic, I need to display the menu and use the user input to
decide what is displayed... BTW in my code i just started with it and i was messing around with using 2 so i was trying to make sure it was an int then i needed to prompt the user to enter more info and so on... The Real Question Is How do to i write a functional loop that takes the user inputed number from 1 to 8 and outputs whatever is inside of that list.

The output should look like this:

Menu:

1) Display Graphic

2) Add Client

3) Add Animal

4) Add Employes

5) List Clients

6) List Anaimals

7) List Employees

8) Quit

Please make a selection: 5

1) Dave Roberts, 123-4567

2) Suzy Smithers, 234-2345

3) Alice Jones, 789-2345

4) Steven Black, 234-4567

```
    int selection1;       
    do                 //sorry didnt copy scanner in, i do have one.
    {
        System.out.println("Menu:");
        System.out.println("1) Display Graphic" );
        System.out.println("2) Add Client");
        System.out.println("3) Add Animal");
        System.out.println("4) Add Employee");
        System.out.println("5) List Clients");
        System.out.println("6) List Animals");
        System.out.println("7) List Employees");
        System.out.println("8) Quit"); 

        System.out.println("Please Select A Number:");
        selection1 = sc.nextInt();

        while(!sc.hasNextInt())             //If you think i should use some other loop to make it
                                             // easier let me know.
        {
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Valid Number:");
        }
        selection1 = sc.nextInt();
        if(selection1 == 2)
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Name:");
                sc.nextLine();

            }while(selection1==0);

        }

    }while(selection1 >0 && selection1 <9); // <-- infinate loop if user enters number between 1 and 8 but i need input from 1 to 8 to start loop.
```

Comment: What are you having problems with specifically? Also, you never created a scanner called `sc`

Comment: Specifically i dont understand what to put in the while condtion that will take the read in value and not make it into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra selection1 = sc.nextInt() above the 1st while loop.  Also, since 8 is quit, the terminating loop condition should be ..&& selection1 < 8 instead of 9.  I mean it looks generally correct, I'd refactor the if chain to something like this:

```
switch (selection1) {
    case 1:
        doDisplayGraphic();
        break;
    case 2:
        doAddClient();
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks i think i'll try it your way, is there a way to make sure it is an int when using switch statement.

Comment: if the sc.haxNextInt() and sc.nextInt() works properly, then selection1 will always be an int.  In anycase if either of those returns the wrong type, you'll get a compile error.

Comment: but sc.nextInt() just prompts some input so if i asked the user for an int and they typed a letter then the program would crash but it cant crash for my program to work, they need to be re prompted to type an int.

Comment: what's the return type of nextInt()?  Also, if you can paste nextInt's body here, we can take a look